# Exclude package from local jar in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a local dependency in a jar that includes a jackson package that conflicts with a package from a remote repository. Is it possible to exclude classes from that jar that come from a certain package?

```
...

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir(dirs: "libs")
}

dependencies {
  compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.8.3'

  compile ('com.me:my-local-jar') {
    // I would like something like this:
    // exclude package: 'com/fasterxml/jackson'
  }
}

...
```